# SQL COUNT nationality with more than one artist and number of artist in that nationality

Tags: mysql, sql

ARTIST

(FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, NATIONALITY)

```
Miro                        Joan                        Spanish                       
Kandinsky                   Wassily                     Russian                       
Klee                        Paul                        German                        
Matisse                     Henri                       French                        
Chagall                     Marc                        French                          
Sargent                     John Singer                 United States                 
Tobey                       Mark                        United States                 
Horiuchi                    Paul                        United States                 
Graves                      Morris                      United States                 
Julio                       Bloxham Smythe              Spanish                       
Basher                      Bigmouth                    Spanish
```

I have to list all the nationalities with more than one artist represented in the database, and the number of artists of that nationality

So the output should be

```
Spanish         3
United states   4
French          2
```

Comment: `..HAVING COUNT(Natinality) > 1`

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` is your friend

```
SELECT NATIONALITY, COUNT(*)
FROM ARTIST
GROUP BY NATIONALITY
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select nationality, 
       count(firstname) as artists -- counts the artists
from mytable
group by nationality -- we group on this, because we want to aggregate the other info
having count(firstname) >1 -- applies a condition AFTER the count
```

Comment: Just for info: This will not take into account the records for which the firstname is NULL

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `group by` clause to apply a group per nationality and then a `having` clause to keep only the nationalities with more than one artist:

```
SELECT   nationality, COUNT(*)
FROM     artist
GROUP BY nationality
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Group By and Having

```
SELECT count(*),`NATIONALITY` 
FROM `ARTIST` 
GROUP BY `NATIONALITY` 
HAVING count(FIRSTNAME) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HAVING is not necessary, simple GROUP BY will do:

```
SELECT NATIONALITY,COUNT(*) FROM ARTIST GROUP BY NATIONALITY;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is a Count function. Try https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-count-function.htm

I think what you need is a general count. It is as simple as:

```
Count(*)
```

I think this question has been asked many times before so to save time try searching the docs next time.